# What is the alternative in the API controllers for not having create and edit?

Tags: laravel, api, model-view-controller, controller

In best practices for writing a Laravel controller.

We notice that there is a create or edit method that returns the view with $roles data to be used in the store or update function
But in the API controller, we notice that there is no create or edit function despite the need for the $roles data

> In the documentation, they provide [API resource routes](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#api-resource-routes) without the create and edit

**What is the alternative to the front-end or mobile developer when the store function is need data from another table in API?**

[laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel)[best-practices](/questions/tagged/best-practices)

[image]

[image]

I tried to write the create function in API controller to return the required data, and I expect that this is not needed!

Comment: you could have another end point that just returns the roles data

Comment: In addition to the suggestion by @lagbox, some documentation that describes your endpoint, the structure of any objects is accepts and the success/failure responses would be a good idea.